# eclipse - missing GWT options

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin, libgdx, google-plugin-eclipse

I am starting with libgdx and recently installed eclipse eclipse GWT plugin (4.2) and other resources. I am struggling with **missing GWT options** in different places. I tried to search different answers but could not locate an answer on SO. Please forgive me in case of duplicacy of question.

Here is the snapshot of the installation - 
[image]

1. The 'Google' and GWT options are missing from preferences page -
   [image]
2. The GWT compile and 'Run as Web Server' options are also missing - 
   [image]

**EDIT** Added plugin snapshot as requested in comments - 
[image]

Comment: Have you created any GWT project and imported in Eclipse?

Comment: I imported an already created GWT project in eclipse, but cannot GWT compile it as I cannot find any option.

Comment: When you restart Eclipse, if you navigate to the error log (Window -> Show View -> Error Log) do you see anything there?

Comment: Also, can you add a screenshot of the "Plugins" tab for Installed Software? Sort by plugin id - I'm curious if the com.google.gwt plugins are listed.

Comment: I think it's better to reinstall the plugin.

Comment: @RajeevDayal- No error in error log regarding plugin and added the snapshot of plugins tab as well.

Comment: @outellou - No progress even on installing plugin. Please note that I have tried it on multiple installations of eclipse for same behaviour, did not get any error upon installations either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is facing similar issue. It seems like the GWT plugins does not function properly for lower versions of eclipse. I installed eclipse kepler, installed plugins (4.3) and everything is working as desired.

Comment: I had Kepler running with the GWT Plugin and installed Luna with that respective Plugin.  Luna did not work.  It's like the plugin was never installed.  I went back to using Kepler. (I've use used Eclipse I & J without trouble in the past)

Answer (score 1):

I know its late .I too faced same kind of issue and resolved it .  I was having eclipse Kepler version 32-bit but my Java version was 64 bit . I uninstalled the current JRE and installed 32-bit . Now I was able to see GWT in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is still struggling with it, there is another layer to this problem now. You need 32 bit Java SDK 8 AND 32 bit eclipse for the addon to work. Last 32 bit eclipse release for Windows was, I believe, the 2018-09 (4.9.0) one. Abandon all hope all who are forced to work with GWT in 2022.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully installed the GWT Eclipse Plugin 3.0.0 in Eclipse 4.16, but was also missing the various menu options. Glancing at the error log (Window > Show View > Error Log) showed a GWT Plugin error who's details contained this: Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))". Running Eclipse under Java 11 (previously Java 8) resolved the error and the GWT menu options now appear as they should.